# Remote Desktop Services Manager shows same users logged in on 2 servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

We have a *Windows Server 2008 R2 x64* terminal server farm. We have a Remote Desktop Connection Brokers server (named **rdcb**) and then 2 Terminal Servers (**rd1** and **rd2**) that are load balanced. When we pull up the Remote Desktop Services Manager to view a remote users screen it does not show users logged into both servers. It shows that servers **rd1** and **rd2** are there but it shows that the same user logged into **rd1** is the same user logged in on **rd2** when in fact a whole different set of users is logged into **rd2**.  The usernames get duplicated.

So it would show something like this when logged into **rd1**:
rd1  user1
rd1  user2
rd1  user3
rd2  user1
rd2  user2
rd2  user3

And then on **rd2** it would show:
rd2  user4
rd2  user5
rd2  user6
rd1  user4
rd1  user5
rd1  user6

We are looking to find a way to fix this so it shows who is logged in on both servers so that we can view their screen without having to login on the console of the other terminal server to resolve their issues. This was working for a while before we shutdown the 3 machines for some maintenance and since they were powered back up it stopped working.

Comment: Are they really logged on to both? Looks like your RD FARM database is out of date. Make sure your broker is running fine.